# A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found

Tags: xcode, xcode4.5, ios-provisioning

I have the classic XCode error when installing.

I have a new device in my company and I want to install one of the app (it's an iPhone 5 and I need the screenshots).

I started renewing the provisioning profile and now the app doesnt work with anyone.

I check everything I found in some threads here, and the mistake continues, restart XCode, and restart the computer, it continues.

I deleted the certificate, and create a new one, tried in other app and works, but it doesn't work in the app I want to install to.

I also created a new appID, a new provisioning profile, still doesnt work.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Any other suggestion?

Comment: So you created a new Provisioning Profile and included the UDID of the new iPhone 5 in it?

Comment: I included all my ios devices, when creating the profile you can check, "Select All", but it doesnt work the iphone 5, neither the iphone 4S, neither the iPad